# Find formula for solution of differential equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

When
\begin{eqnarray*}
y'[x] &=& \frac{r y[x] }{ x } \; \;\text{and} \;\; y[1] = a \\
y[x] &=& a x^r
\end{eqnarray*}
Use derivative formulas to explain the output.

What I have so far:

We know that 
\begin{eqnarray*}
y'[x] = r y[x] = k e^{rx}
\end{eqnarray*}
So we can rewrite as 
\begin{eqnarray*}
y[x] = \frac{k e^{rx} } { x}
\end{eqnarray*}
To get the value of k:
\begin{eqnarray*}
a = \frac{k e^{r} }{ 1} \\
k = \frac{a}{e^r}
\end{eqnarray*}
So now we have
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{(a/(e^r)) e^{rx} } { x}
\end{eqnarray*}
But when I plug this into a derivative calculator I get a solution much different than $y[x] = a x^r$. Perhaps I am approaching this wrong. What is the correct way to approach this problem?

Comment: Is $y=ax^r given to you as part of the problem?

Comment: That is quite a major edit ... can you check this is your intended meaning ?

Comment: Also, $y'=ry/x$, not just $ry$.

Comment: @probably_someone The OP appears to be trying to use the solution to $y'=ry$ to get a soution to $y'=ry/x$ ... someone needs explain how the technique of seperation of variables should be applied in each of these cases ...

Comment: I am trying to figure out how y[x] = a x^r when y'[x] = (r y[x])/x and  y[1] == a using derivative formulas

Comment: The solution should end at y[x] = a x^r

Comment: search this site for "seperation of variables" ... you will find lots of good examples of the technique you require ... send me a message if you still need some help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$y'[x] = \dfrac{r y[x] }{ x }$ leads to $xy'[x] = r y[x]$ and not to $y'[x] = r y[x]$

As you say the exercise is stated, I think we only need to check that differentiating the given function, $y[x]=ax^r$, we get the ODE:

$y'[x]=(ax^r)'=arx^{r-1}=\dfrac{rax^r}{x}=\dfrac{r y[x] }{ x }$

Anyway, we can solve the ODE and compare the solution with the given one. As said in the comments, you can use the separation of varibles technique in this ODE:

$\dfrac{dy}{dx}=\dfrac{ry}{ x }\;;\dfrac{dy}{y}=\dfrac{dx\,r}{x}$, then

$\ln\vert y\vert=r\ln\vert x\vert+K\;;\ln\vert y\vert=\ln\vert x\vert^r+\ln k\;;\ln\vert y\vert=\ln k\vert x\vert^r$ and because the equality or logarithms entails equality of their arguments,

$y=kx^r$ for some k. But $y[1]=a$, so $k·1^r=a$ and we recover the given solution, $y[x]=ax^r$