# How does y[x]=a*E^(r - r/x) when y′[x]=(ry[x])x^2 and y[1]=a

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I am trying to solve the problem very similar to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2333341/find-formula-for-solution-of-differential-equation)
but stumbled :(

**y'[x] = (r y[x])/x^2** with with **y(1) = a**

The output in Mathematica will be **a*E^(r - r/x)**

I need to use the derivative formulas to explain the Mathematica output.

Can somebody please explain the logic behind it?

What am I trying to do?

I am deriving the given equation and the output and receive their derivatives.

I guess I need to reconcile them somehow, but not sure how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to solve the [differential equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_equation) $y'(x) = \frac{r y(x)}{x^2}$ with initial condition $y(1) = a$. That is, you are trying to find a function $y(x)$ (on some interval containing $x=1$) whose derivative at every $x$ in the interval is $r y(x)/x^2$, where $r$ is a constant, and whose value at $x=1$ is $a$.  The answer is $y(x) = a e^{r - r/x}$ for $x > 0$.  To see that this is correct,

1. Differentiate the answer to see that $$y'(x) = \frac{a r}{x^2} e^{r-r/x} = \frac{r y(x)}{x^2}$$
2. Substitute $x=1$ in the answer to see that $y(1) = a$.